# Apache perl script plain text output

Tags: apache-2.4, scripting, perl

Can anyone suggest why my perl script is rendering as plain text:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use FindBin;
BEGIN {
  lib->import($FindBin::Bin) unless $ENV{mod_perl}
}
require 'lsmb-request.pl';
```

My Directory directives are as follows:

```
Alias /ledgersmb /opt/ledgersmb/
<Directory /opt/ledgersmb>
  RewriteRule ^/ledgersmb/?$ /ledgersmb/login.pl [R]
  RewriteRule rest/(.*) /ledgersmb/rest-handler.pl/$1

  Options +ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  AddHandler cgi-script .pl
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Apache version:

```
[dave@Threepwood opt]# sudo apachectl -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.23 (Unix)
Server built:   Jul  5 2016 07:34:37
```

Permissions:

```
[dave@Threepwood ~]$ ls -l /opt/ledgersmb/setup.pl 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 http dave 119 Aug 20 14:53 /opt/ledgersmb/setup.pl
[dave@Threepwood ~]$ ls -l /opt/ledgersmb/login.pl 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 http dave 119 Aug 20 14:53 /opt/ledgersmb/login.pl
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When the **contents** of a script get rendered as plain text, rather than the script being executed, that the might be observed for instance when the correct [module for CGI](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_cgi.html) support has not been loaded with for instance `LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so` .

If the **output** of the script renders as plain text, that is a failing of the script author. One of the [first requirements](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/cgi.html#writing) in writing a CGI script:

> all output from your CGI program must be preceded by a MIME-type header. This is HTTP header that tells the client what sort of content it is receiving.

Without a (correct) MIME-type header the browser will have to guess what the content is.  The browser might default to trying to display your output as plain text.

Comment: The contents of the script are output verbatim and rendered in the browser as a text file. The scripts are part of the ledegerSMB (http://ledgersmb.org/) open source package and I'm loathe to edit them.

Answer (score -1):

Check that the script is executable:

```
chmod +x path-to-script.pl
```

Comment: Permissions are as added to the OP.

Comment: I read the statement "rendering as plain text" as meaning the text in the script is being returned, rather than being executed. If the script is being executed and is generating html, but the html is not being processed properly by the browser, check that the script is producing http response headers- a "Content-Type: text/html" at minimum, followed by 2 crlf pairs, before any generated html.

Comment: The script file is presented in the browser as is, including the shebang line and other statements as per the first snippet in the OP.

Comment: Try replacing the Alias with ScriptAlias in the apache config. However ledgersmb documentation says that CGI is no longer supported. What version of ledgersmb is this?

Comment: According to the release_notes, it is 1.4.34-dev

Comment: Is there an .htaccess file in /opt/ledgersmb ?

Comment: No. There are no hidden files in the directory.

Comment: One other idea that comes to mind is that some other piece of configuration is loading mod_perl and that is getting in the way of running these scripts as CGIs. If there is some mention of mod_perl, best to disable it.

Comment: Finally, the configuration above presumably is as provided by smbledger. It's strange, the Rewrite rules, which impact the logical path, will not be applied until after the logical path has been mapped to a physical path. Try scrapping it- delete the Rewrite rules and change the Alias to ScriptAlias.

Comment: First I removed the Rewrite rules. No change. Then I removed the Alias line and substituted ScriptAlias. The page still renders with the text of the script file. I'm baffled.

Comment: Very strange indeed. Is it certain that apache in fact is using that config file? Does gobbledegook in the config cause apache to fail to restart?

Comment: Yes. If I remove the Alias (or ScriptAlias) line, then the page fails to load: "Object not found". There is an option to use nginx instead of apache: I might just cut my loses and see if I can get that to work. Apache is clearly not loading the perl interpreter.

Comment: Good clue. One clarification- strictly speaking, apache should not be loading the interpreter into memory, something that happens when using mod_perl (which also may be an option for ledgersmb). The configuration above is for CGI; in that configuration, apache should be essentially shelling out to execute those scripts, and reading results from stdout. Though the config above is sufficient to support CGI execution, something is evidently preventing it, hence the earlier query about mod_perl. But it may be worth running apache with trace level logging and posting the log.

Comment: Set the loglevel to trace8. Got this in /var/log/httpd/error.log: `
[Wed Sep 07 16:22:03.589016 2016] [mpm_event:trace6] [pid 6958:tid 139710085117696] event.c(1586): connections: 0 (clogged: 0 write-completion: 0 keep-alive: 0 lingering: 0 suspended: 0)
` I can't see anything there which might explain it.

Comment: There should be more information in the log resulting from accepting and servicing the request. Well- it looks like ledgersmb's desired approach for the future is to run inside of a Starman webserver. This can be easily proxied to by either apache or nginx. Have you tried running it under Starman?

Comment: No, I hadn't actually heard of Starman before now. I assumed it was a replacement http server for apache or nginx.

Comment: It is an http server, but specifically designed to host perl web applications. It looks like it is the recommended approach for running ledgersmb. Most of the rest of the web ecosystem works this way- java application servers run java applications; python servers run python applications, etc. Now those are often still "proxied" by an nginx or apache, but the integration is much more straightforward. The nginx or apache webserver handles tasks like serving static files that application servers are less good at, and speaks HTTP to the application server for application requests.

Comment: I've given up on this machine and have installed on a server I have which runs Apache 2.2. The odd thing is that I now have a configuration which works perfectly using Seamonkey as the browser, but if I use Firefox, the browser offers to download the perl script. :?

Comment: Hmm, sounds like the application/octet-stream problem. See for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7581797/firefox-php-headers-and-application-octet-stream If the app doesnt send a Content-type header, both apache and firefox will guess at how to categorize it, and if they guess wrong then application/octet-stream is the "i give up" answer. If you accept the download and look at what it receives, it should be the html or whatever the app returns.